# What are the new "Order" and "OrderDescending" in .NET 7?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

After a few months not working with LINQ, today I realized Intellisense gave me [`OrderDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderdescending?view=net-7.0) instead of `OrderByDescending` (due to my muscle memory). The documentation is not very clear on what it does or why I should use it instead of `OrderByDescending`. The docs also say it's new and is only added in .NET 7.

What is this new method for and when do you use it?

Comment: Any time you needed to write `OrderBy(x => x)` you can now write `Order()`

Comment: @JL0PD that's it? I was excited thinking it's some fancy new API lol.

Comment: It's an optimised sort which doesn't need the `keySelector` argument because it sorts the entire elements rather than needing to select some part of the element. Also note that there's also an equivalent `Order()` you can use instead of `OrderBy()`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson ah that makes sense. I hope it's actually written like that instead of just a call to `OrderBy(x => x)` in its implementation.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Unfortunately, at least for `IEnumerable`, the implementation simply calls `OrderBy(x => x)`: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/70525/files#diff-a6eeb575d79166a5a13a20a0af34718d318483e1b0eabeaaaa15c2429cb45695R44

Comment: @LukeVo No it doesn't - if it can, [it uses `OrderedImplicitlyStableEnumerable`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/OrderBy.cs,18b2160348972821) to sort (which would be used for things such as `int`, `short` etc) if [TypeIsImplictlyStable()](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/OrderBy.cs,8c5238b57919b41a,references) returns `true` for the type being sorted.

Comment: @MatthewWatson you are correct! I was looking at the wrong place.

Comment: It is rather limited I suppose, but then again, it's quite often that you want to sort `int` or `short` arrays. It doesn't include sorting `double` - I don't know the reason for that for sure, but I'm guessing it's due to `Double.NaN`, `Double.Infinity` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is new method added in .NET 7 to perform "identity" sort i.e. it is equivalent of:

```cs
.OrderByDescending(x => x)
```

See the proposal - [[API Proposal]: Enumerable.Order and OrderDescending](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/67194#issue-1182004119) and [current `Enumerable.OrderDescending` implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f040d861ecf650e26821430486f934f391389316/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/OrderBy.cs#L90).

Comment: Found the [discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/67194) finally. You are correct. Somehow Google keeps returning result for `OrderByDescending` even when I put "OrderDescending" in quotes.

Comment: It also allows a custom comparer.